VBA Hlookup multiple rows
I'am trying to use HLookup with vba, but when i try the vba code i can't apply it to multiple rows, it can only be used for single rows "J2", i need HLookup vba code for many rows "J2" till "J1001", and Lookup value "A2" till "A1001", what vba code should i use?
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

Range("J2").Value = WorksheetFunction.HLookup(Range("A2"), Sheets("Input").Range("C4:ALN14"), 3, False)

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub


What cells are being changed?  Are you changing J2 or A2 in the code above, or is that what ever cell is changed recalc J2?

You want to run a thousand look-ups every time a cell is changed? Or do you want just the line that is changed to be refreshed?

@Nathan_Sav The changed cell is in the “input” sheet

@CLR I only want the changed row to be refreshed.

The following sub will refresh your look-up on any range you give it:
Sub refresh_rows(rg As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For r = rg.Row To rg.Row + rg.Rows.Count - 1
        Range("J" & r).Value = WorksheetFunction.HLookup(Range("A" & r).Value, _
            Sheets("Input").Range("C4:ALN14"), 3, False)
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

So you can use it to refresh them all with:
refresh_rows range("J2:J1001")

Or you can refresh only those rows that were updated by the user with:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    refresh_rows Target
End Sub

